# How many tiles are cached?

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I've got an application that uses osmdroid 4.3. As I know it's avalilable to set cache overshoot. But how can I get the number of cached tiles? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: there's no programmatic way to get access to that information as of right now.

Per the javadoc
 Initial tile cache size. The size will be increased as required by calling
     * {@link LRUMapTileCache#ensureCapacity(int)} The tile cache will always be at least 3x3.

Solution: alter the code.
In LRUMapTileCache, add a getter for the size.
In MapTileCache, you'll need to add a getter to access LRUMapTileCache's size
Finally, in MapTileProviderBase, add a getter for the size

then you'll be able to get the cache size from

`mapView.getTileProvider().getCacheSize()`;